# Visual connotation associated with “lucid”

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, adjectives

I’m interested in the definition and connotation of *lucid* when it comes to physical objects: what does a lucid object look like?

From *Merriam-Webster*:

> - suffused with light : luminous
> - translucent <snorkeling in the lucid sea>

From *Dictionary.com*:

> - shining or bright.
> - clear; pellucid; transparent.

From these definitions, it seems like the term *lucid* can describe stars in the night sky, light bulbs, the ocean in Aruba, and wine glasses.

Is this true? Are some of those objects more correctly associated with the word *lucid* than with the words *bright*, *glowing*, or *transparent*?

Also, links to any images containing lucid objects would be great.

Comment: [google  images for lucid](https://www.google.com/search?q=lucid&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X)

Comment: Tried that before asking this question. It doesn't work.

Comment: In what way doesn't it work. As is, your question is not very constructive. We only get that you're not happy with some situation regarding the term 'lucid' and some objects. But it is not clear how you are unhappy there. You need to give some specific examples of when the word lucid is either good or not.

Comment: Did you try searching for lucid? You get advertisements of products with the term "lucid" in them, along with a few other seemingly-random images.

Comment: I see people flying as in a dream. I see a close up of an eye. I see a butterfly and swirly beaches. Oh... you mean on google images? There too. Can you edit your question to make it more lucid?

Comment: I think you're a bit confused on what the transparent and translucent definitions are meaning. When referring to the term lucid they aren't meaning just that light can pass through but also connotations of clarity.

Comment: I have always thought of [lucid](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/lucid) as having connotations of clarity and simplicity.

Comment: I don't think you would generally apply the word "lucid" to objects specifically, but more to images of them.  "Lucid" is more often applied to dreams, memories or images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*The following examples from the* public-domain [New English Dictionary](http://archive.org/details/oed6aarch) *should give you a good idea of how* lucid *has been used in each of its senses:*

**Lucid** (l<sup>i</sup>*ū*·sid), *a.* [ad. L. *lūcid-us*, f. *lūcēre* to shine. Cf. F. *lucide.*]

**1.** Bright, shining, luminous, resplendent. Now *poet.* and *techn. Ent.* and *Bot.* = Smooth and shining. *Astr.* Of a star: Visible to the naked eye.

> **1591** S<sub><sup>PENSER</sup></sub> *M. Hubberd* 1259 With his azure wings he cleav’d The liquid clowdes, and lucid firmament.
>   **1654** V<sub><sup>ILVAIN</sup></sub> *Theol. Treat.* ii. 45 The Air is not a lucid body like the Sun.
>   **1667** M<sub><sup>ILTON</sup></sub> *P. L.* XI. 240 Over his lucid Armes A Militarie Vest of purple flowd.
>   **1693** B<sub><sup>ENTLEY</sup></sub> *Boyle Lect.* vii. 5 There are great multitudes of lucid Starrs even beyond the reach of the best Telescopes.
>   **1772–84** C<sub><sup>OOK</sup></sub> *Voy.* (1790) V. 1743 Supposed to be an animal which contributes to that lucid appearance often observed at sea in the night.
>   **1797** *Encycl. Brit.* (ed. 3) III. 443/2 [*Botany.*] A Surface is .. Lucid, as if it were illuminated.
>   **1800** H<sub><sup>ULME</sup></sub> in *Phil. Trans.* XC. 180 Another lucid dead glow-worm was put into warm water, at 114°.
>   **1833** T<sub><sup>ENNYSON</sup></sub> *Poems* 60 Her lucid neck Shone ivorylike.
>   **1845** W<sub><sup>ESTWOOD</sup></sub> *Brit. Moths* II. 221 *Aphelosetia lucidella* (the lucid).
>   **1847** W. E. S<sub><sup>TEELE</sup></sub> *Field Bot.* Gloss. 16 *Lucid*, with a bright and shining surface.
>   **1870–74** J. T<sub><sup>HOMSON</sup></sub> *City Dreadf. Nt.* 1. i, The lucid morning’s fragrant breath.
>   **1893** S<sub><sup>IR</sup></sub> R. B<sub><sup>ALL</sup></sub> *Story Sun* 333 Beta Lyræ .. is among the coolest of the lucid stars.
>   *fig. a* **1652** J. S<sub><sup>MITH</sup></sub> *Sel. Disc.* iv. 112 The intellectual world, being .. made all lucid, intellectual, and shining with the sunbeams of eternal truth.
>   **1742** B<sub><sup>ARNARD</sup></sub> *Char. Lady E. Hastings* 39 To bring them into the lucid Path of Vertue and Religion.

**2.** Translucid, pellucid, clear.

> **1620** V<sub><sup>ENNER</sup></sub> *Via Recta* Introd. 4 The lucide and cleare substance of it [*sc.* air].
>   **1647** H. M<sub><sup>ORE</sup></sub> *Poems* 5 Thus they stood by that good lucid spring Of living bliss.
>   **1725** P<sub><sup>OPE</sup></sub> *Odyss.* VI. 102 The lucid wave a spacious bason fills.
>   **1791** C<sub><sup>OWPER</sup></sub> *Odyss.* III. I The sun, emerging from the lucid waves.
>   **1832** L<sub><sup>YTTON</sup></sub> *Eugene A.* I. x, How singularly pure and lucid the atmosphere becomes.
>   **1882** F. W. H. M<sub><sup>YERS</sup></sub> *Renewal of Youth* 314 Let many a heat distil Her lucid essence from the resurgent ill.

**3. Lucid interval.** Also in early use in med.L. form (pl.) *lucida intervalla.*

**a.** A period of temporary sanity occurring between attacks of lunacy. (So F. *intervalle lucide.*) † Formerly also, in wider use, an interval of apparent health between the attacks or periods of a disease.

> [The Latin phrase ‘non est compos mentis, sed gaudet lucidis intervallis’ is common in English legal documents from the 13th to the 15 c.; so also in the med.L. commentators on Justinian’s *Institutes.* For the etymological notion presumably underlying the expression, cf. **c**.]
>   **1603** S<sub><sup>IR</sup></sub> C. H<sub><sup>EYDON</sup></sub> *Jud. Astrol.* xxi. 425 Sometimes shee [the moon] graunteth to them [lunatics] *Lucida interualla.*
>   **1625** B. J<sub><sup>ONSON</sup></sub> *Staple of N.* v. i, They are almost mad! But I forgiue their *Lucida Interualla.*
>   *c* **1645** H<sub><sup>OWELL</sup></sub> *Lett.* (1650) II. 42, I had a shrewd disease hung lately upon me. .. After som gentle slumbers, and unusuall dreames .. I had a lucid intervall.
>   *a* **1655** V<sub><sup>INES</sup></sub> *Lord’s Supper* (1677) 213 A mad man may have lucid intervals.
>   **1659** S<sub><sup>TANLEY</sup></sub> *Hist. Philos.* XIII. (1701) 624/2 As for that Pain which is lasting, it is not only gentle, but hath many lucid intervals.
>   **1686** J. D<sub><sup>UNTON</sup></sub> *Lett. fr. New-Eng.* (1867) 23, I had between whiles those lucid intervals [in sea-sickness].
>   **1769** B<sub><sup>LACKSTONE</sup></sub> *Comm.* IV. 25 If a lunatic hath lucid intervals of understanding, he shall answer for what he does in those intervals.
>   **1839** I. R<sub><sup>AY</sup></sub> *Med. Jurispr. Insanity* xiv. 298 It was decided by the court, Sir Willian Wynne, that she had a lucid interval, while making the will.
>   *a* **1859** M<sub><sup>ACAULAY</sup></sub> *Hist. Eng.* XXV. V. 294 James lingered three days longer. He was occasionally sensible during a few minutes, and, during one of these lucid intervals [etc.].

**b.** *transf.* and *fig.* A period of rest or calm in the midst of tumult or confusion; an interval during which there is a reversion to a normal, reasonalbe, or desirable condition.

> **1581** W. A<sub><sup>LLEN</sup></sub> *Apol. Eng. Seminaries* iii. 22 Which [Arianisme] though it troubled the world some hundred yeres together, yet it .. had *lucida interualla*, gaue seasons of calme and rest to holy Bishops.
>   **1622** B<sub><sup>ACON</sup></sub> *Hen. VII* Wks. 1861 VI. 32 Which [dissensions] although they had had .. lucid intervals and happy pauses; yet did they ever hang over the kingdom.
>   **1650** F<sub><sup>ULLER</sup></sub> *Pisgah* IV. ii. 34 The devil heaped afflictions upon him, allowing him [Job] no lucid intervalls.
>   **1682** D<sub><sup>RYDEN</sup></sub> *MacFl.* 22 Some beams of wit on other souls may fall, Strike through and make a lucid interval.
>   **1751** S<sub><sup>MOLLETT</sup></sub> *Per. Pic.* xxii, Neither was his whole time devoted to the riotous extravagances of youth. He enjoyed many lucid intervals.
>   **1822** R. G. W<sub><sup>ALLACE</sup></sub> 15 *Yrs. in India* 194 It is quite impossible to transact business with a chief, except in that lucid interval between .. one debauch and .. another.
>   **1900** *19th Cent.* Sept. 386 Italy is just passing through one of these lucid intervals.

**¶ c.** In the etymological sense: An interval of sunshine in a storm.

> **1655** T<sub><sup>UCKNEY</sup></sub> *Good Day well Impr.* 8 Some short *lucida intervalla,* as the sun in a rainy day, looking out now and then a little.
>   **1749** C<sub><sup>APT</sup></sub>. S<sub><sup>TANDIGE</sup></sub> in *Naval Chron.* III. 207 It being then day-light, and a lucid interval between showers of snow.

**4.** Marked by clearness of reasoning, expression, or arrangement; easily intelligible.

> **1786** C<sub><sup>OURTENAY</sup></sub> *Lit. & Mor. Charac. Johnson* 24 And lucid vigour mark’d the general style.
>   **1803** *Med. Jrnl.* X. 182 Arranged in that lucid order which is so necessary to assist the student.
>   **1838** D<sub><sup>ICKENS</sup></sub> *Nich. Nick.* xxiv, Mrs. Curdle sat listening to this lucid explanation.
>   **1871** M<sub><sup>ORLEY</sup></sub> *Voltaire* (1886) 7 His expression was incomparably lucid.
>   **1876** C. M. D<sub><sup>AVIES</sup></sub> *Unorth. Lond.* 103 The sermon was long but lucid.

**5.** Of persons: Clear in intellect; rational, sane.

> **1843** C<sub><sup>ARLYLE</sup></sub> *Past & Pr.* II. i, Any lucid simple-hearted soul like him.
>   **1859** G. M<sub><sup>EREDITH</sup></sub> *R. Feverel* xxx, T<sub><sup>WO</sup></sub> apparently lucid people.
>   **1887** *Times* 11 Aug. 5/2, I believe you are insane on that one point. On everything else you are lucid and bright.

**6.** With agent-noun: That performs the action implied in a lucid manner.

> **1879** M<sup>c</sup>C<sub><sup>ARTHY</sup></sub> *Own Times* II. xxix. 372 There never was a more lucid and candid reasoner.